# Frame Rate For Tracking People

Tags: computer-vision, tracking

I am trying to track people in an airport area, where the distance of the people from the camera range from 0m - roughly 2m. Currently I am using a CCTV with 25Hz. However, sometimes it seems a little low as a framerate as people tend to jump from one frame to another.

**Question:** Can roughly tell me what CCTV framerate in hertz do you recommend or else how can I figure out the best one for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

25 frames per second should be good enough.  Given a time difference of 40ms between frames, and given a typical fast walking pace of about 2m/s, you get motion of about 8cm between two frames.  Even at relatively short distance from the camera this should be doable.

Comment: Thank you @photon. I appreciate your answer. However I did not clearly understand from where you got the 8cm between to frames. Isn't 8cm alot? Thank you.

Comment: If a person moves 2 meters every second while walking, the average distance of movement between frames (1/25 second) is 8cm.  If a person is 2m from the camera, a movement of 8cm in the real world would translate to a movement in the image space, but not a huge one.

Comment: You can also perform a test.  Take a picture of an object, then move it 8cm and take another picture.  Check the motion between the images

Comment: I understood you better now. Thank you very much @Photon :)